# ng-scrollable not working at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to get ng-scrollable to work with my application. I followed the instructions and installed it on my site, but I just can't get it to work.

Fearing that something was stopping it working on my site, I decided to set up a codepen, and it still doesn't work:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/JYzmax

I am trying to achieve a horizontal scrollbar that scrolls left and right when I use my mouse wheel.
I added the code (initially) like this:

```
<div ng-scrollable="{ scrollX: 'bottom', scrollY: 'none' }" style="height: 100%; width: 10000px;"><section class="page" ui-view metro></section></div>
```

but this didn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: All you're doing is to __display__ a scroll-bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the scrollbars appear if you set the width and the height to 50px. It looks like the scrollbars only appear when there is content too wide to fit in the set width/height of the div.

Try this code instead:

```
<div ng-app="Scroll">
  <div ng-scrollable="{ scrollX: 'bottom', scrollY: 'left' }" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; border:1px solid red;">
    <h1>This is a test</h1>
    <div style="margin-top:10000px; margin-left:10000px;">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```